# Combining ranges in SQL/BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to combine adjoining date ranges in BigQuery.

I have a table like this:

```
ID   START                     END
1    2019-01-18 17:34:58 UTC   2019-02-18 12:14:59 UTC
1    2019-02-18 06:04:39 UTC   2019-02-18 08:05:05 UTC
1    2019-02-18 08:05:05 UTC   2019-02-18 10:06:05 UTC
1    2019-02-18 10:06:05 UTC   2019-02-19 11:16:15 UTC
2    2019-01-19 06:02:29 UTC   2019-01-29 11:02:23 UTC
```

Since the three middle rows represent a single range split into three pieces, I want to combine them so the table looks like this:

```
ID   START                     END
1    2019-01-18 17:34:58 UTC   2019-02-18 12:14:59 UTC
1    2019-02-18 06:04:39 UTC   2019-02-19 11:16:15 UTC
2    2019-01-19 06:02:29 UTC   2019-01-29 11:02:23 UTC
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine where the ranges start.  In your case, they seem to have exact matching end and starts, so you can use `lag()` to identify where groups start. A cumulative count of the starts provides a grouping id, which can be used for aggregation:

```
select id, min(start) as start, max(end) as end
from (select t.*, countif(prev_end is null or prev_end <> start) over (partition by id order by start) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(end) over (partition by id order by start) as prev_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

If the groups can overlaps, then a cumulative maximum usually does the trick:

```
select id, min(start) as start, max(end) as end
from (select t.*, countif(prev_end is null or prev_end <> start) over (partition by id order by start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end) over (partition by id order by start rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```